# Different ways about Passing 2D array of pointer to function C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, 2d

I met some problems when passing 2d-array to functions today, later I found some solutions like A and B.
I knew that 2d-array is stored in a continuous memory as 1d. So in my opinion, there is no 2 dimensional points in fact, compiler split this continuous numbers and made '2 dimensional' concept.

My question is: in C after I explicitly told compiler the parameter is a 'int**', why it did not pass a '2 dimensional' point?

Someone may point out "in C you did not told compiler the group-length", I think it knew this information because if you try to reexplain the 12 elements' plain memory into arr[2][6] it will be error like "void printArr(int _arr[][6], int _columns, int _rows)".

A little confused please help...

```
int arr[][3]={{1,2,3},{5,6,7},{9,10,11},{13,14,15}};

void printArr(int _arr[][3], int _columns, int _rows){ //----->A
void printArr(int (* _arr)[3], int _columns, int _rows){//---->B
void printArr(int** _arr, int _columns, int _rows){//--------->C
    for(int r=0; r< _rows; r++){
        for (int c=0; c<_columns; c++)
            //printf("%4d,", _arr[r][c]);
            printf("%4d,", *(*(_arr+r)+c));
    }   
}
int main(){
    printArr(arr, columns, rows);
}
```

Comment: See if http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html answers your question. There is a lot to read, but you really, really need a good understanding of arrays and pointers to write proper C code. Nobody said it would be easy.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays decay into pointers, that means if you have an array of arrays `int arr[x][y]` it can decay into a pointer to array `int (*arr)[y]`.

`int ** arr` therefore would be a version of decayed array of pointers `int *arr[x]`, which is an incompatible type with your array.

Answer (score 0):

int ** is a pointer to a pointer to int, not a pointer to a 2-dim array.

Answer (score 0):

Style note: don't use leading underscores for your identifiers; such names are reserved for the implementation.

Solution `B` explicitly captures what is happening; in the call to `printArr`, the *expression* `arr` is implicitly converted from "4-element array of 3-element array of int" to "pointer to 3-element array of int".

However, in the context of a function parameter declaration, the notation `T a[]` is synonymous with `T *a`; therefore, solution `A` is effectively the same as solution `B`.

Answer (score -1):

You are right that the compiler reserves a contiguous block of memory so knowing that you can do something like my example. It also works with 1d arrays, ie: printArr((int*)arr, 1, 10);

```
void printArr(int *_arr, int _columns, int _rows) {
    for(int r = 0; r < _rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < _columns; c++) {
            printf("%4d,", _arr[r * _columns + c]);
        }
    }   
}

int arr[][3]={{1,2,3},{5,6,7},{9,10,11},{13,14,15}};
printArr((int*)arr, 3, 4);
```

I think you were very close with C.  The two changes are parameterizing with int* rather than int** and your offset computation was incorrect.